# Can't the model look lighter?

Tags: animation, 2d

[image]

It's a 3D model, but I'm going to draw it on the bottom when I draw 2D.

The 3D model is too dark, can't it be transparent?

I tried the x-ray mode, but the objects looked overlapped. I hope it's transparent from what I see now

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: When you turn on the x-ray you will see any faces that overlap because it's a 3D model. Transparent material will result in the same. Backface culling can reduce the effect a bit but you probably will still see the overlaps. In the *Solid* shading mode (key Z) the shading options are limited. Have you tried to assign a white material to the model and switch to *Material Preview* shading mode? (I'm not sure if this is an option for GP drawings). Tick [X] Ambient Occlusion in the Eevee render settings to get more depth. https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5xyn.jpg

Comment: Not a Blender answer, but for what you seem to be asking I'd render as-is, then in a 2D app (GIMP, Photoshop, etc) layer it over an appropriate solid-color layer and adjust the render layer's transparency.  The same can be done in Blender's Compositor, but GIMP's easier IMHO.

Comment: I gave animation to 3D model. I was going to do a 2D drawing with that as a rough sketch of 3d model. I'm changing the outline to green. And I'm drawing.Thank you to those who answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

I found out after watching the YouTube course.
You can adjust the fade object value.